# Crontab behavior?

Tags: raspbian

I have a shell script that uses a mapfile command.

```
#!/bin/sh

mapfile all_lines < "/var/www/weewx/temp.txt"

a="${all_lines[1]}"
b="${all_lines[3]}"
```

If i run the shell script from the command line as in:

```
./overlay.sh
```

it runs without error.

if however I run it from crontab I get the following error:

```
/home/pi/WeatherCam/overlay.sh: 10: /home/pi/WeatherCam/overlay.sh: mapfile: not found
```

Can anyone explain why this occurs and how to fix it?
Thanks for and and all help!!!

EDIT: from another forum it was suggested I change it to a bash script (#!/bin/bash) and that solved the problem... it now runs without error from crontab. 
The strange thing is when I ran
    $ which mapfile 
nothing is returned? (see answer below) all quite confusing!

Answer (score 4):

When run under `cron`, your environment is not passed in, so within your script, you often need to specify the full path to binaries. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/mapfile all_lines < "/var/www/weewx/temp.txt"

a="${all_lines[1]}"
b="${all_lines[3]}"
```

You'll need to find what the real path is. `which mapfile` may be of help.